# Speeding up a function that outputs products with repeats in Python

Tags: python, string, python-itertools

I've written a function which returns a list of all possible 'products' of a string with repeats (for a spell check program):

```
def productRepeats(string):
    comboList = []

    for item in [p for p in product(string, repeat = len(list(string)))]:
        if item not in comboList:
            comboList.append("".join(item))

    return list(set(comboList))
```

Therefore, when `print(productRepeats("PIP"))` is inputted, he output is (I don't care what the order is):

```
['PII', 'IIP', 'PPI', 'IPI', 'IPP', 'PPP', 'PIP', 'III']
```

However, if I try anything greater than 5 digits (PIIIIP), it takes about 30 seconds to output, even though there are only 64 ways

Is there any way I could speed this up, as getting the list for the string 'GERAWUHGP', for instance, takes well over half an hour?

Comment: Make `comboList` a `set`, so lookups are O(1), not O(n).

Comment: @user3483203: Actually, with the code as written, the OP *does* need to convert to a `set`, because they're testing for `item in comboList` but adding `''.join(item)` to `comboList`, so their check doesn't actually filter out any duplicates.

Comment: Note that the size of your product grows so quickly that your approach won't be very practical for nontrivial strings in the real world.  I mean, the word "practical" has not one but two duplicate letters, and it would _still_ generate a list 40M long.  A word like "duplicate" would have a list over 387 million long, which would take a few minutes to generate and 20G of memory if you materialized them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of tricks you can use:

1. Use a list comprehension or `map` to perform your iteration.
2. As [@jwodder explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51002422/9209546), use `set(string)` to avoid checking for duplicates at a later stage.

Here's a demo. I'm seeing a ~900x improvement for "hello":

```
from itertools import product

def productRepeats(string):
    comboList = []

    for item in [p for p in product(string, repeat = len(list(string)))]:
        if item not in comboList:
            comboList.append("".join(item))

    return list(set(comboList))

def productRepeats2(string):
    return list(map(''.join, product(set(string), repeat=len(string))))

assert set(productRepeats2('hello')) == set(productRepeats('hello'))

%timeit productRepeats('hello')   # 127 ms
%timeit productRepeats2('hello')  # 143 µs
```

Answer (score 4):

### Eliminate duplicates *before* calling `product()`

`product(seq, repeat=len(seq))` will produce duplicate results if & only if `seq` contains any duplicate elements; e.g., `product('ABC', repeat=3)` will have no duplicates, but `product('ABA', repeat=3)` will have some duplicates because `A` will be selected more than once (and that'll be compounded by the fact that 'ABA' is used as an argument three times).  Filter out any duplicates from `string` first and then pass the result to `product`, and you'll be able to completely drop the post-`product` duplicate check, so you can just return the result of `product` directly:

```
def productRepeats(string):
    return product(set(string), repeat=len(string))
```

Comment: Useful, but I need the output as a list of strings, not an object. Also, when I add list() onto the return, the output is a list of tuples